# Rails default_scope order not being applied to ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

Rails default_scope order not being applied to ActiveAdmin. This is the scope from the model `default_scope { order(date_time: :desc) }`. This works in the console but not in ActiveAdmin.

**app/admin/reservations.rb**

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :name
  column :number_of_guests
  column 'Date', :date_time, sortable: :date_time do |reservation|
    reservation.date_time.strftime('%B %-d, %Y %I:%M %P')
  end
  column :status do |reservation|
    case reservation.status
    when 'Pending'
      status_tag reservation.status, class: 'warning'
    when 'Confirmed'
      status_tag reservation.status, class: 'ok'
    when 'Closed'
      status_tag reservation.status
    end
  end
  column :created_at do |reservation|
    reservation.created_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y %I:%M %P')
  end
  column :updated_at do |reservation|
    reservation.updated_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y %I:%M %P')
  end
  actions
end
```

**log when visiting index**

```
Started GET "/admin/reservations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 05:56:19 +0800
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Admin::ReservationsController#index as HTML               
  AdminUser Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering /home/gilbertlcsndle/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.2.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "reservations" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "reservations" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations"                         
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "reservations" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Reservation Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" ORDER BY "reservations"."id" desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "reservations"."number_of_guests" FROM "reservations" ORDER BY number_of_guests asc
   (0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "reservations"."status" FROM "reservations" ORDER BY status asc
  Rendered /home/gilbertlcsndle/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.2.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (943.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1024ms (Views: 952.3ms | ActiveRecord: 18.9ms)
```

Comment: ActiveAdmin should use the scope (It uses mine). I think it applies its own ordering on render tho. You'll probably have to redefine the `index` block with your sort preferences. See https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html.

Comment: @JacobVanus checkout the updated question. I added the code and log.

Comment: Did you configure anything else in your reservations activeadmin?

Comment: @nayiaw no. Checkout the code above